# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in swift Json parsing

Tags: swift

In My code I getting the crash like unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value but i dont know to how to solve the issue so please say what mistake i made in this code and how to solve the issue, i totaly confused for last few days because i am new for swift?

Here I Give my code.....

```
            let dataArr : NSArray = responseObject.valueForKeyPath("response.result") as! NSArray
            print(dataArr)

            for vartype : AnyObject in dataArr
            {
                let titleStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("title") as! NSString
                let messageStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("message") as! NSString
                let date_updatedStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("date_updated") as! NSString
                let postprofilephotoStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("postprofilephoto") as! NSString
                let imgattachStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("attachments.image") as! NSString  -----> //From This line I get the issue.
                let audioattachStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("attachments.audio") as! NSString
                let videoattachoStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("attachments.video") as! NSString
                let ptypeStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("ptype") as! NSString
                let attachmentStr : NSString = vartype.valueForKey("attachments") as! NSString

            }                
            self.tableView.reloadData()

            print("JSON: " + responseObject.description)
        },
        failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,
            error: NSError!) in
            print("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)


        })
```

Comment: Any types ending in `!` will be force unwrapped at runtime. If a force unwrapped variable contains nil when it is unwrapped you will see this error. Swift forces you to handle `nil` values at compile time. Try replacing `!` with `?` and changing your code so it compiles.

Comment: In which place i want to replace? ..@nielsbot

Answer (score 0):

Please check your object `vartype`. Clearly the key path `attachments.image` does not exists in it.

When you try to force unwrap an optional without checking `nil`, this crash is bound to happen (if that optional is actually `nil`).

To safeguard from this kind of crash use `if let` syntax for unwrapping optionals.

**EDIT :** Post OP comments - try this out:

```
if let value : AnyObject = vartype.valueForKey("attachments.image") {
    imgattachStr = value as! NSString
}
```

You should do this safe check for all optionals force unwrapping.

Comment: In which place i want to use if let syntax..@Abhinav

Comment: Sure, please post the results!

Comment: Shouldn't that be `valueForKeyPath()`?